# Localization of mobile apps - Any resources available for the basics?

Tags: android, ios, localization, translation, localizable.strings

I have an IOS app I intend to localize into a bunch of languages at a point. Instead of going to a translation service and translate everything from scratch, I wonder if there are any resources to get the very basics translated? Resources such as open source localized strings (does that exist?), databases, web services (not Google translate which doesn't work very well for some languages and technology terms).

In my case, I don't have too many sentences, so it's more a question of single words. I imagine words such as the below are very frequently translated for mobile apps:

*camera roll, cancel, delete, double-tap, swipe, notification, home, share, ok etc.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ray has some good [examples](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial).

And so does [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/)

You can also use translating services such as [this one](http://applingua.com)

And this jkublcek wrote a decent [translater](https://github.com/jkubicek/AutoLocalize) that use Google's API for auto translation.

Comment: I have missed Apple Glot and the translation packages that can be downloaded from Apple. By the looks of it, that seems to be exactly what I was after. Will give that a go.