# Pre-built localization strings for multiple languages

Tags: android, ios, localization, translation

It is a tedious task to localize app's for multiple languages, and very often the same work is done over and over again:
For example, phrases like "OK", "Cancel" are in almost every android app.

[Localization of mobile apps - Any resources available for the basics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445080/localization-of-mobile-apps-any-resources-available-for-the-basics)
This question is 3 years old, I wonder if anything changed since then.

Are there any comprehensive libraries/collections which take care of this? So that I only have to translate the actually app-specific strings?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Google Translator Toolkit. It supports the various localization files. It also has support for iOS and Android localization files. 
Example: For Android you can upload your strings.xml you can select to which files you want to get it translated. It is automatically translated by Google Translate. It uses different colors to display how sure Google Translate is about the translation, and gives feedback about things that needs to be changed in the translations.

You can also use a translation memory. This is a database with saved translations. You can create a personal Translation memory. This contains all the translations you made. You can also use the global TM.

> The global TM saves and stores translations from Translator Toolkit users everywhere. Please note that the global TM is available for anyone to see and use.

You read more about it on [the support page](https://support.google.com/translatortoolkit/answer/6306375?hl=en&ref_topic=6306365)

It has an editor build in which allows you to change the automatically translated words/sentences. You can export the translations as strings.xml again, so you can use them straightaway in your Android project.

A disadvantage: I don't think it is possible to switch between localization formats, so you have to translate all sentences for both the iOS and Android version.

You can read more about it on the [support page](https://support.google.com/translatortoolkit/?hl=en#topic=6306364)

Comment: I was hoping to find something predefined. The automatic translation does not really work well enough

Comment: @Mike76 I forget to mention it also uses a translation memory. You can create a personal Translation memory. This contains all the translations you made. You can also use the global TM. The global TM saves and stores translations from Translator Toolkit users everywhere. Please note that the global TM is available for anyone to see and use. You read more about here: https://support.google.com/translatortoolkit/answer/6306375?hl=en&ref_topic=6306365